# Getting the size of the type of a zero-length array element in a structure

Tags: c, gcc

Maybe the title is confusing, but the idea is simple. Given the following structure:

```
struct z {
    uint64_t _a;
    uint64_t _b;
    struct {
        char _c[64];
        uint64_t _d;
    } data[0];
} __attribute__((packed));
```

How might one get the size of **the type of** the anonymous inner struct `data`? I do not want to name the struct and clutter the namespace, but I do need its size when computing the total length of what a serialized buffer would look like with a non-zero `data` trailer.

[If you try this](https://onlinegdb.com/rygoB2e43H) you'll find something similar to:

```
struct z *p;
sizeof(struct z) == 16
sizeof(*p) == 16
sizeof(p->data) == 0
```

These results are expected. However, what I was hoping to see was the following:

```
sizeof(typeof(p->data)) == 72
```

But, unfortunately, I still get

```
sizeof(typeof(p->data)) == 0
```

I thought it might be because the struct was unnamed, but after providing it with a name you'll find the earlier results are still true.

Is there a way to get the size of an anonymous inner zero-length structure?

Comment: Why'd you expect 72?

Comment: @SouravGhosh `64 chars + sizeof(uint64_t) = 72`. Assuming sizeof(char) is 1.

Comment: Note that zero-length array elements are a non-portable GCC extension that [actually violates the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p1): "If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero."  You should probably use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).  You have to track the number of elements in such an array yourself.

Comment: `sizeof type->p_data[0]` which in itself is of course illegal but perhaps should not matter. But indeed you should use FAM since it seems you're using GCC anyway.

Comment: @sherrellbc ahh, packed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I considered it at first, but I ran into issues while testing. `sizeof(p->data)` is zero when the length of the array is specified explicitly as zero. When using a FAM it'll actually throw a compile-time error. Seems like a bug. At least it does with the version of GCC used on [this site](https://onlinegdb.com/r1AP1WN3B), anyway.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Curious as to why that expression is illegal, because it does indeed work. Since `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, you aren't strictly accessing out of the array bounds.

Comment: *Seems like a bug*  It's not a bug.  What you're doing is akin to trying to get the number of elements in an array by using `sizeof()` on a pointer:  There's a chunk of memory that your code dynamically allocates at runtime that you have a reference to the beginning of.  The `sizeof()` the reference is independent of the size of the chunk of memory it refers to.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I've been using FAM/ZSA for years. I understand what you're saying, trust me. I just don't understand why it's apparently so difficult to get the size of a FAM _that is not either `char` or `uint8_t` typed_. And what I mentioned does seem like a bug. The compile-time behavior is different for the case when the size if specified as zero or left out. Strictly speaking, both should be zero. Semantically their use is the same at runtime.

Comment: You could give the inner struct a tag name so that you can call out the type name in a `sizeof` expression.

Comment: @dbush The intent is to use this structure solely for serializing data. I really don't care what the inner struct's name is, so I left it anonymous. Otherwise I would clutter the struct namespace with another `struct serialized_data`, etc etc and it's just not necessary.

Comment: @sherrellbc Do you see a problem using `sizeof p->data[0]` _and_ a FAM?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I don't, because it emits the behavior that I would expect `sizeof(typeof(FAM))` to emit. But the latter gives zero despite the defined element entity _of_ the FAM being distinctly non-zero in the case I show above.

Comment: `sizeof sizeof p->data[0]` differs from `sizeof(typeof(FAM))` as the first is the size of an array element and the latter is the size of the array.  Why expect these two to provide the same result?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica. Perhaps the issue for me has been a violation of that assumption. Namely that I expected `typeof(FAM)` to evaluate to the element type of the array, not the array itself.

Comment: Yes.  Operators like `sizeof` do not convert an array to a  "pointer ... to the initial element of the array" per  "Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type “array of type” is converted to an expression with type “pointer to type” that points to the initial element of the array object" C17dr § 6.3.2.2 3.  `sizeof(array)` is the array size, not the element size.

Answer (score 4):

I would use:

```
sizeof(p->data[0])
```

Because it's inside `sizeof` and therefore not evaluated, `p->data[0]` does not actually dereference `p->data`. The compiler only figures out the type.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  It gets the size of the anonymous struct in a well-defined manner.

Answer (score 3):

> but I do need its size when computing the total length of what a serialized buffer would look like with a non-zero data trailer

You can't do that with `sizeof()`.  You must keep track of the size yourself.

[Per the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) (bolding mine - and note it well):

> Declaring zero-length arrays is allowed in GNU C as an extension. A
>   zero-length array can be useful as the last element of a structure
>   that is really a header for a variable-length object:
>
> ```
> struct line {
>   int length;
>   char contents[0];
> };
>
> struct line *thisline = (struct line *)
>   malloc (sizeof (struct line) + this_length);
> thisline->length = this_length;
> ```
>
> Although **the size of a zero-length array is zero**, an array member of
>   this kind may increase the size of the enclosing type as a result of
>   tail padding. ...

Note how the example code keeps track of the number of elements in the array.

Comment: In general I have not run into this issue because I typically would specify the FAM as a `char` or `uint8_t` type. But I am in a situation where the trailing data is a bit more complicated, so I intended to have a FAM structure as shown above. While it does work, I ran into the issue about getting the type _compile-time_ size. I _do_ understand it's element size is zero, obviously. I'm not sure why this is so hard to do, or apparently requires illegal expressions like `sizeof(p->data[0])` to achieve (which _does_ work).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I think you missed the point of my question. My structure above is not the same as yours. I understand `contents` is a reference to the start of some `length` sized block of data. I get it. I was hoping for a little more structure for my `contents`-like element to prevent ugliness like that second bit of code.

Comment: @sherrellbc Unfortunately, you can't, no more than you can get the size of an `int` array you allocated with `malloc()` by using `sizeof()` on the pointer returned from `malloc()`. The point of my answer is to provide the actual reference that states  you simply can not use `sizeof()` on a zero-length array that's used as a placeholder/reference for a larger array at the end of a structure.  There's a reason this coding paradigm has the name "struct hack". GCC's zero-length arrays and standard C flexible array members are IMO just useful attempts to shoehorn the hack into standardized code.

Comment: @sherrellbc How do you get the length when it's an array of `char` or `uint8_t` type?

Comment: I get that `sizeof(contents)` is, and should be, zero in this example. What I do not understand is why something like `sizeof(typeof(contents))` is not equivalent to `sizeof(char)` here. That's why I was hoping `sizeof(typeof(p->data))` would give me the size of the _type of_ the flexible array member. But it also just returns zero, despite have a real _non-zero type_. But maybe the real answer is just "FAM were not meant for non-char/uint8_t-typed elements`.

Comment: @user253751 **I'm not asking about the length of the the FAM**. I'm asking about the size of the **TYPE OF** the element. Read the OP.

Comment: @sherrellbc *What I do not understand is why something like `sizeof(typeof(contents))` is not equivalent to `sizeof(char)` here.*  It's **exactly** equivalent.  Your `contents` are a zero-length array, which **by definition** (the GCC documentation) has zero size.  If you want the size of an **element** of the array you need something like `sizeof(typeof(contents[0]))` or `sizeof(typeof(*contents))`.  You've been asking "Why is `sizeof( char[ 10 ] )` ten and not one?"

Comment: I'll concede. GCC defines the size of a zero-length array to be zero. This implies that `sizeof(FAM)` and `sizeof(typeof(FAM))` are fundamentally the same expression in this case. My hope was that the size of the type of element represented _by the_ FAM would be non-zero, but GCC was not written this way. Clearly the intent was never to have a FAM not be typed with `char` or `uint8_t`, and the data contents to remain opaque in the definition. It's a bit limiting to force simply typed (char/uint8_t) FAM data trailers. `sizeof(p->data[0])` is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

just name it. if instead of saying

```
struct {
    char _c[64];
    uint64_t _d;
} data[0];
```

you say

```
struct data {
    char _c[64];
    uint64_t _d;
} data[0];
```

then `sizeof(struct data)`  will tell you it's sizeof.